# Show that $W^{1,p}(a,b) \subset C^{0,1-\frac{1}{p}}\left([a,b]\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces, bounded-variation

Show that $W^{1,p}(a,b) \subset C^{0,1-\frac{1}{p}}\left([a,b]\right)$
Where the second space are Hölder continuous function with $\gamma = 1-1/p$.

I know that in dimension $n =1$ a function $u$ belonging to $W^{1,p}(a,b)$ is absolutely continuous so I think I should proceed from here and then prove that
\begin{equation}
|u(y)-u(x)| \le C|x-y|^{1-1/p}
\end{equation}

Can you help me?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but isn't this Morrey's inequality?

Comment: Yes it is! It's just a special case of Morrey's inequality when n=1. But my professor assigned this exercise before talking of Sobolev inequalities. So I think that it must be shown using absolutely continuous/bounded variation arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u$ is absolutely continuous and $u' \in L^{p}$. So, by Holder's inequality,  $|u(x)-u(y)|=|\int_x^{y} u'(t)dt| \leq \|u'\|_p (\int_x^{y} 1^{q}dt)^{1/q}$ where $\frac 1 p +\frac 1 q=1$. Hence the inequality holds with $C=\|u'\|_p $.

Comment: You meant $|u(y) - u(x)|$ ?

Comment: What is the difference? $|a|=|-a|$ right? @JamesArten